# Deserialize different JSON structure

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I need to deserialize different JSON string value structures returned from remote API. When I get result, I don't know what structure is returned without parsing it.

Error response:

```
{
    "type": "invalid_phone_number",
    "code": 400,
    "error": "Invalid phone number",
    "detail": null
}
```

Success response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "status": "accepted",
        "sms_id": "tmpde1bcd4b1d1",
        "price": 0.02,
        "credit": 215.81380,
        "number": "XYZ"
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid to inspect returned JSON value and then apply correct Jackson `ObjectMapper`. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this a spring-boot application?

Comment: @Anchit Yes, it is.

Comment: Please refer @RestControllerAdvice

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the HTTP response code before you parse the response.  For 4xx or 5xx you can use the error mapping and for 200 response you can deserialize using your data structure.

Here is an example:

```
try {

    ParameterizedTypeReference<R> typeRef = new ParameterizedTypeReference<R>() { };
    ResponseEntity<R> response = getRestOperations().exchange( apiPath, method, entity, typeRef );

    // parse success message here...
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> map = ( LinkedHashMap<String, Object> ) response.getBody();
    return mapper.convertValue( map, clazz );
} catch ( HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e ) {

    if ( e.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND ) {
        // parse error message here...
    }

}
```